# How to implement custom deserializer for type Boolean in spray json

Tags: json, scala, spray, spray-json

I have a couple of `Boolean` attributes in my API model and would like to accept `true`/`false` as well as `1`/`0` values. My first idea was to implement custom formatter:

```
object UserJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {

    implicit object MyBooleanJsonFormat extends JsonFormat[Boolean] {
        def write(value: Boolean): JsString = {
            return JsString(value.toString)
        }

        def read(value: JsValue) = {
            value match {
                case JsString("1") => true
                case JsString("0") => false
                case JsString("true") => true
                case JsString("false") => false
                case _ => throw new DeserializationException("Not a boolean")
            }
        }
    }

    implicit val userFormat = jsonFormat15(User.apply)
}
```

where `User` is a model with `Boolean` attributes. Unfortunately above solution has no effect - `1/0` are not accepted as Booleans. Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fixing some issues with types and pattern matching it seems to work:

```
implicit object MyBooleanJsonFormat extends JsonFormat[Boolean] {
    def write(value: Boolean): JsBoolean = {
        return JsBoolean(value)
    }

    def read(value: JsValue) = {
        value match {
            case JsNumber(n) if n == 1 => true
            case JsNumber(n) if n == 0 => false
            case JsBoolean(true) => true
            case JsBoolean(false) => false
            case _ => throw new DeserializationException("Not a boolean")
        }
    }
}
```